# sessionScope variables are null

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I am trying to get handle on sessionScope variables but thay are not being recognized immediately on the next page.  Sorry for lots of info here but any ideas?

First XCpage has a customControl named ccMultipleLoadHandlers.  In the custom control there is a repeat control which gets a handle on data in a Domino view and the last column is a link which sets several  sessionScope variables and opens another XPage. Here is the code for the link.

```
                                        <xp:link
                                            escape="true"
                                            id="link3"
                                            text="${langBean.labelEdit}"
                                            value="/RemanRental.xsp">
                                            <xp:this.onclick><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.calitm=""}]]></xp:this.onclick>
                                            <xp:eventHandler
                                                event="onclick"
                                                submit="true"
                                                refreshMode="norefresh">
                                                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:importPackage(com.mycorpname);
dBar.info("Entering Link for ccRentMultLoadHandView")
try{
    var doc
    var calitm
    var caitm
    sessionScope.rentDisplay = "MultLoadHandDisplay";
    var hostURL = configBean.getValue("HostURL")
    var hostName = configBean.getValue("HostCommon")
    var dbName = configBean.getValue("rentalDbPath")
    var webPath = configBean.getValue("WebsiteURL")
    try{
        //var rtn
        var urlPath = hostURL+webPath
        dBar.info("urlPath:  "+urlPath)
        if(rowData.isDocument()){
            dBar.error("rowData is Document");
            doc = rowData.getDocument();
            if (doc != null){
                calitm = doc.getItemValue("CALITM");
                modelNbr = calitm[0];
                dBar.error("1. modelNbr="+modelNbr);
                modelNbr =modelNbr.slice(2);
                dBar.error("2. modelNbr="+modelNbr);
                sessionScope.calitm = modelNbr;
                dBar.error("CALITM IS "+sessionScope.calitm)
                caitm = doc.getItemValue("CAITM");
                sessionScope.caitm = caitm[0];
                dBar.error("ccRentMultLoadHandView >>>> CAITM IS "+sessionScope.caitm)
                var fam = doc.getItemValue("family");
                sessionScope.family=fam[0];
                var strURL = urlPath+"/Rental.xsp?"
                dBar.info("Returning:  "+urlPath+"/Rental.xsp?databaseName="+hostName+"!!"+dbName+"&documentId="+rowData.getUniversalID()+"&action=openDocument");
                sessionScope.urlPath = urlPath+"/RemanRental.xsp?databaseName="+hostName+"!!"+dbName+"&documentId="+rowData.getUniversalID()+"&action=openDocument"
                return urlPath+"/Rental.xsp?databaseName="+hostName+"!!"+dbName+"&documentId="+rowData.getUniversalID()+"&action=openDocument"
        } else {
                dBar.info("Unable to get handle on document");
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        dBar.info("1. ccRentMultLoadHandView >> link error >>>Unable to get handle on document.  " + e.toString());
        println("1. ccRentMultLoadHandView >> link error>>>>  " + e.toString());
        return e.toString()
    }

} catch (e) {
    dBar.info("2. ccRentMultLoadHandView >> link try error >> Unable to get handle on document.  " + e.toString());
        println("2. ccRentMultLoadHandView >> link try error>>>>  " + e.toString());
    return e.toString()
}}]]></xp:this.action>
                                            </xp:eventHandler>
                                        </xp:link>
```

The opened XPage has a custom control named ccRentMultLoadHandleDisplay which has code in the afterPageLoad event. That code  is:

```
importPackage(com.mycorpname);
dBar.error(">>>> sessionScope.rentDisplay is "+sessionScope.rentDisplay+" <<<<")
if (sessionScope.rentDisplay=="MultLoadHandDisplay"){
try{

// ***** Get RENTAL Specs ****      
            var table = configBean.JdbcTable_03;
            sessionScope.jdbcTable = table;
            dBar.error("ccRentMultLoadHandDisplay>>>sessionScope.rentDisplay = "+sessionScope.rentDisplay);
            var caitm = sessionScope.caitm;
            dBar.info("ccCartonlampDisplay>>var caitm is:  "+caitm);
            var calitm = sessionScope.calitm;
            dBar.info("ccCartonlampDisplay>>var calitm is:  "+calitm);
            getComponent("modelNbr").setValue(calitm);
            dBar.warn("rentBean.getMultLoadHandData("+caitm+","+sessionScope.Region+","+ table+","+ sessionScope.family+")")
            var returnMap=new com.ibm.jscript.std.ObjectObject();
            returnMap = rentBean.getMultLoadHandData(caitm,sessionScope.Region, table, sessionScope.family);
            dBar.info( "Got Rental Specs");
            
            var i;
            var rmc //return map component
            var value
            //dBar.info("return map size: " + returnArray.size());
            sessionScope.returnArray=true
            //dBar.info("returnArray.getCACLLB()= "+returnArray.getCACLLB());
        
            // we will now set the values not set above.  what they gets set to depends on values set in othe fields above
            dBar.error("ccRentMultLoadHandDisplay>>>Entering CartonClampDisplay data");
            for ( i in returnMap ){
                dBar.warn("ccRentMultLoadHandDisplay>>>i = "+i.toUpperCase());
                rmc = i.toUpperCase();
                var value = returnMap[i];
                value = Number(returnMap[i])/100;
                //dBar.warn("RemanRental>>>value = "+value);
                var fieldVal;
                switch(rmc.trim()){
                    case "CAACMT":
                        fieldVal = String(returnMap[i]);
                        dBar.warn("ccRentMultLoadHandDisplay>>>String(value) CAACMT = "+fieldVal);  
                        getComponent(rmc.trim()).setValue(fieldVal);
                        break;
                    case "CAMFCL":
                        fieldVal = String(returnMap[i]);
                        dBar.warn("ccRentMultLoadHandDisplay>>>String(value) CAMFCL = "+fieldVal);  
                        getComponent(rmc.trim()).setValue(fieldVal);
                        dBar.warn(rmc.trim()+":  "+getComponent(rmc.trim()).getValue());
                        break;
                    default:
                        dBar.warn("ccRentMultLoadHandDisplay>>>value = "+value);
                        getComponent(rmc.trim()).setValue(value);
                        dBar.warn(rmc.trim()+":  "+getComponent(rmc.trim()).getValue());
                        break;
                }
                }
} catch(e){
    println("There was an error in ccRentCartonDisplay afterPageLoaad");
    dBar.error("ccRentMultLoadHandDisplay---->Error in afterPageLoad:  "+ e.toString());
    println("ccRentMultLoadHandDisplay-----> Error in afterPageLoad: "+ e.toString());
}
}
```

The problem is that the sessionsScope variables are null but if I reload the page they are there and code properly sets fields

Here are messages that are displayed in the Debug Tool Bar

XXXXXX

09:29:40    3. sizeGen=

09:29:40    3. funct=

09:29:40    2. modelNbr=

09:29:40    1. modelNbr=

09:29:40    ENTERING IMAGE TRY CODE

09:29:40    RemanRental>>>Entering afterPageLoad

09:29:40    >>>> sessionScope.rentDisplay is null <<<<

09:29:40    >>>> before page load: sessionScope.rentDisplay is null <<<<

XXXXXXX

And here are the recorded sessionScoped variables:

XXXXXXXX
caitm:  2362656

calitm:  25G-FDS-1200

rentDisplay:  MultLoadHandDisplay

rentView:  Multiple Load Handlers

XXXXXXXX

The resulted page is:
[image]
If I reload the pae second page, then the sessionScope variables are recognized
Resulted page is:
[image]

Comment: I think that the problem is that you are using onclick for server side JS which is for client side JS only (so that code does nothing except generating errors in the browser console, I believe)  - and that you are using norefresh as refreshMode

Comment: The onClick event is for server side javascript and yes i am using norefresh:  refreshMode="norefresh".  I added image of onClick event above

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom control named reoladPage, then added client side set timeout script block per Knut Herrmann suggestion in this posting:  [Need to reload an XPage after a few seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67725667/need-to-reload-an-xpage-after-a-few-seconds/67727002#67727002).
I added the custom control to my XPage.  Problem solved.