# Need to reload an XPage after a few seconds

Tags: xpages

I am trying to get an XPage to reload after 1 second but can't figure out the code to do it.  Does anyone have an example on how to do this in XPages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use JavaScript's setTimeout() function in Client Side JavaScript code block `<xp:scriptBlock` to execute a reload after a second (1000 ms):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlockReload">
        <xp:this.value>
        <![CDATA[
            setTimeout(function() {
                 location.reload();
            }, 1000)
        ]]>
        </xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>
    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:new Date().getTime()}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:text>
</xp:view>
```

In case you just want to refresh a part of your XPage instead of reloading it completely you can replace

```xml
location.reload();
```

with

```xml
XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:computedField1}", {})
```

It will refresh computedField1 once after a second. It is up to you what kind of id you specify. It could be the id of a panel which includes several or even all components of your XPage.

Comment: Thank you Knut, That worked for me.  I appreciate it very much